# How do I stop from creating an endless sequence of events?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of user preferences with a listener on change.

A few of the preferences need to interact. For instance, if I change preference A to "off" then Preference D should also be shown as "off."

I realize what I have is a simple implementation - which worked when all preferences were independent. But if the user changes Preference A, and my code checks for their choice then changes Preference D for them, then I get endless triggering of events. How do I gracefully design around this trap I've created?

```
$('.updateUserDetails').on('change', function (e) {
  console.log('Detected change in user prefs...');
  var chromeLog = $("#loggingModeAccount").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
  var historyPosition = parseInt($("#historyPosDD").val(), 10);

  if (chromeLog === 0){
    console.log('Turning history OFF in Chrome...');
    $("#historyPosDD").val("127");
    historyPosition = 127;    //  Set to default
  } else {
    console.log('Chrome logging ON...');
    $("#historyPosDD").val("3");
    historyPosition = 3;    //  Set to default
});
```

Both #loggingModeAccount and #historyPosDD have the class . updateUserDetails. So when my code updates $("#historyPosDD").val based on the change to #loggingModeAccount I create an endless loop.

I've tried including e.stopPropagation(); in various places with no luck...

How do I design my way out of this? Any help/direction appreciated.

Comment: what about identifying the two elements with different ids, so they are unique, and group the common code with functions? so inside the two different `onChange` callbacks you call the func for common code?

Comment: Only change the value if necessary, i.e. check it before changing it.

Comment: @quirimmo, won't that just create endless ping-ponging? One changed? So the other is updated. Which causes the first to update...

Comment: @ChrisG: what happens when I DO change it...then endless loop.

Comment: nope, if you change this code `$('.updateUserDetails').on('change'` to two different `$('#field1').on('change'` and `$('#field2').on('change'`, they won't react to the same changes anymore

Comment: @11teenth No, not at all. First, you DO change it. The 2nd time you don't because it already has the correct value. The End.

Comment: Thank you @quirimmo and ChrisG...I had a good number of preferences and was avoiding backtracking...but I implemented what you suggested (for the two interdependent values) and have a catch-all for the rest...works now. Thank you!

Comment: Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/g8etqr2c/